# Why do I need to explicitly enable data migrations in Azure?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-sql-database

I'm working through this tutorial:

[Deploying an ASP.NET Web Application to a Windows Azure Web Site and SQL Database](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/)

In the second part "Enable Migrations and create the database" I need to use the NuGet Package Manager console to enter a series of commends:

1. enable-migrations -ContextTypeName ToDoListApp.Models.ToDoDb
2. add-migration-initial
3. update-database

Why do I need to do this explicitly?  Shouldn't this be wrapped up in the publish process?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0):

The migrations process is separate from Azure. You can have an MVC 4 project that uses database migrations but the database is not hosted on Azure. The commands you are referencing simply enable the migrations in any MVC 4 project.

I find updating the database dangerous, so I actually prefer it to be separated from the publishing process because this way someone on your team is able to update the logic of the website without pushing updates to the database.